# Proving two rings are not isomorphic by considering the number of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The problem:

> Determine if $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^3+1)$ are isomorphic or not, and justify your answer.

(This is a homework problem.)

I think the rings are not isomorphic. My justification goes:

> Elements of $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ are $\overline{0}$, $\overline{1}$, $\overline{x}$, $\overline{x + 1}$.
> Elements of $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^3 + 1)$ are $\overline{0}$, $\overline{1}$, $\overline{x}$, $\overline{x + 1}$, $\overline{x^2}$, $\overline{x^2 + 1}$, $\overline{x^2 + x}$, $\overline{x^2 + x + 1}$.
> Since the number of elements are different, the rings are not isomorphic.

Is it sufficient to conclude that the rings are not isomorphic just because they contain a different number of elements?

Also, if the problem is changed so that I cannot enumerate the elements like in the justification above (say, if I were to determine if $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^3 + 1)$ are isomorphic as rings), is there a general strategy that tackles the problem?

Comment: $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+1)$ has no zero divisors, but $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^3+1)$ has. This is another method. In general, one can often determine some "invariant"  of the quotient rings, which distinguishes them. There are many possibilities. However, there is not a simple "formula" that always tackles the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the cardinalities are different then there is no bijection between the rings, and so no isomorphism.

Over $\mathbb{Q}$ the problem is a bit more interesting. Note that the polynomial $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, and so $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a field. On the other hand, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3+1)$ is not a field, because $x^3+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: One can also observe that they have different dimension as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces.

Comment: @DanielHast That's also true. Any ring isomorphism of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ is also an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras, and so preserves dimension. That will not work over other fields though.

Comment: Yeah, good point, your approach is more general since it works over any integral domain.